# Get all unique object properties from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, lodash

Let's imagine I have an array of objects e.g.

```
 [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
 }, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "car": true
 }, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
 }]
```

I want to get all the unique property names from this array of objects, so the result will be:

```
[firstName, lastName, car]
```

**How can I do it:**

I can imagine that it's possible to do this with something like this:

```
function getPropertiesNames(obj){
  var arr = [];
  for(var name in obj) {
    if(arr.indexOf(name) != -1) arr.push(name);
  }
 return arr;
}
```

**Why I need it:**

I will have to make a table of multiple objects. Because each object can be a bit different I need unique property names.  However I am going to do it in angularJS so it's kind of a bad option for me to once use loop to get property names for `<th>` and once again use loop with `<tr ng-repeat></tr>` to display values.

**What i want:**

Is there some option to get all unique property names from an array of objects without iterating it? Maybe some lodash or build in JS function which I don't know?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A solution using only:

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var data = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var uniqueKeys = Object.keys(data.reduce(function(result, obj) {
  return Object.assign(result, obj);
}, {}))

console.log(uniqueKeys);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. It looks a bit more readable. However may I ask you if it will be faster in compare with regular loop or answers in this questions?

Comment: It will not be faster than a regular loop. I'm not sure if there's a significant difference. The main benefits of using these standard methods is that they're safe (as in, they follow the js standards), and easy to read and understand. Have a look at the polyfills in the linked articles to get a feel of what they're doing under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the array of objects to a single object. Then get the keys from the merged object:

```
Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...array))
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const array = [{firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"},{firstName:"Anna",car:true},{firstName:"Peter",lastName:"Jones"}],
      unique = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...array))

console.log(unique)
```

---

Another option is to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as callback to [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). This returns an array of *all* the keys. Then, create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique keys and use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the set to an array.

```
const keys = input.flatMap(Object.keys),
      unique = Array.from(new Set(keys));
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const input=[{firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"},{firstName:"Anna",car:true},{firstName:"Peter",lastName:"Jones"}],
      unique = Array.from(new Set(input.flatMap(Object.keys)));

console.log(unique)
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, you can use

```
const keys = [].concat(...input.map(Object.keys)),
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `map()` and `keys()` to return keys of each object and then `union()` and `flatten()`

```js
var data = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}]

var result = _.union(_.flatten(_.map(data, (e) => _.keys(e))));
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @NenadVracar, I would have 2 questions about it.
1. What this: `...` means?
2. Any idea about performance in compare with my option or one from Tholle

Comment: That is spread operator, you can use flatten instead, like in update.

Comment: You can also use `uniq` like this `var result = _.uniq(_.flatten(_.map(data, (e) => _.keys(e))));`

Comment: Thank you, please do not hesitate to add it to your answer :) I like that there are multiple options. Do you have any knowleage about speed of all of this options in compare with my code or codes below from other ppl?

Comment: You don't need to wrap `_.keys()` in an arrow function. Just pass it like this: `_.map(data, _.keys)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get away from checking each key in each object. You could accomplish it with e.g [**reduce**](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```
var result = _.reduce(array, function(memory, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if(memory.indexOf(key) === -1) memory.push(key)
  }
  return memory;
}, []);
```

```js
var array = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var result = _.reduce(array, function(memory, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if(memory.indexOf(key) === -1) memory.push(key)
  }
  return memory;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could store the keys in a new object, and just extract the keys:

```
var temp = _.reduce(array, function(memory, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    memory[key] = null;
  }
  return memory;
}, {});
var result = Object.keys(temp);
```

```js
var array = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var temp = _.reduce(array, function(memory, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    memory[key] = null;
  }
  return memory;
}, {});
var result = Object.keys(temp);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Tholle, may I ask you what's that advantage of using this instead of clasic loop?  I bet i miss something but from documentation it sounds like clasic loop

Comment: @Andurit You're welcome! If you have a big array, a regular loop will probably be faster. If you have a small array, and you are like me and find reduce more readable, you might go with one of these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var result = [];
array.reduce( function(pre, item) {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(i){
        if (result.indexOf(i) === -1){
            result.push(i);
        }
    });
});
```

```js
var array = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var result = [];
array.reduce( function(pre, item) {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(i){
        if (result.indexOf(i) === -1){
            result.push(i);
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this:

```
var source = [{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe"
 }, {
"firstName": "Anna",
"car": true
 }, {
"firstName": "Peter",
"lastName": "Jones"
 }];

uniq(source);

function uniq(source){
   var result = source.reduce(function(p, c) {

     Object.keys(c).forEach(function(key) {
         p[key] = true;
     });

     return p;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution without any library.

```
var array = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "car": true
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var arr = [],merged,uniqArray;

array.forEach(function(val){ //Getting all properties
   arr.push(Object.keys(val))
 });

merged = [].concat.apply([], arr);//Merging all array to single array

merged.forEach(function(val){
  if(uniqArray.indexOf(val)== -1){// Getting uniqe values
   uniqArray.push(val)
}})
```

RESULT

```
["firstName", "lastName", "car"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using flat

```js
const arr = 
[{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
 }, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "car": true
 }, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
 }].map(obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)).flat()
const s = [...new Set(arr)]
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner option:

```
[...new Set(a.map(Object.keys).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)))];
```

Comment: I see someone didn't like it.